# UINavigationController, force stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Question about UINavigationController

Let's say I have 5 UiViewController each one push the next one.

vc1 --> vc2 --> vc3 --> vc4  --> vc5
vc1 <-- vc2 <-- vc3 <-- vc4  <-- vc5

If I want to add a UIButton on vc1 who push to vc4, but I want also vc4 to go to vc3 at popViewController

vc1 --> --> vc4
vc1 <-- vc2 <-- vc3 <-- vc4

Was the best way to use:  ?

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:NO];
```

Comment: Yes, use `setViewControllers:animated:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:NO];
```

There is no animation

So,try this In vc1

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated: NO]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated: NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc4 animated: YES];
```

Comment: isn't it the same as  `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self,[vc2 new],[vc3 new],[vc4 new]] animated:YES];` because I get the same result of your suggestion

Comment: Do you see v2 and v3 in the during the animation?

Comment: That's the point.
Using:
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated: NO]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated: NO];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc4 animated: YES];

= I can see v2 and v3. (no luck, because looks like a easy way!)

I'll test setViewControllers and see.

Comment: [self.navigationController setViewControllers:newViewControllers animated:NO];   
Work fine.  But is there a way to force viewdidload to be called on vc3 ?

Comment: vc3.view = Force a viewDidLoad  :)